# C# WPF поставить иконку для окна

Tags: c#, wpf

Добавил в resources новую иконку, для окна в свойстве icon указал ее. В XAML добавило

```
Icon="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/favicon.ico"
```

Получаю ошибку 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.'

Comment: А как вы подключаете иконку? Как Resource или Embedded Resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня работает так:

```
Icon="pack://application:,,,/Resources/favicon.ico"
```

Проверьте также, что иконка добавлена как Resource (а не Embedded Resource).

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо поставить Copy always в propertis